# Passing an object of a class to a method in the class

Tags: class, python-2.7, methods

I wrote a simple date `class` for practice but I can't seem to pass the objects in the class to the methods within the class. The class is supposed to be able to accept test dates, correct them if they are out of range and then print the correct date. Here is the code

```
class Date:
    month = int
    day = int
    year = int
    def setDate(self, month, day, year)
        HIGH_MONTH = 12
        HIGHEST_DAYS = ['none',31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        if month > HIGH_MONTH:
            month = HIGH_MONTH
        elif month < 1:
            month = 1
        else:
            month = month
        if day > HIGHEST_DAYS[month]:
            day = HIGHEST_DAYS[month]
        elif day < 1:
            day = 1
        else:
            day = day
    def showDate(self):
        print 'Date:',month,'/',day,'/',year


#These are my tests
birthday=Date()
graduation=Date()
birthday.month=6
birthday.day=24
birthday.year=1984
graduation.setDate(5,36,2016)
birthday.showDate()
graduation.showDate()
```

What I get is a `NameError: global name 'month' is not defined`

Comment: Just saying, it might be more pythonic for you to initialize your list as `HIGHEST_DAYS = [None,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]` rather than the above.

Comment: Thanks, I get the 'not pythonic' a lot. It's probably because I'm translating from pseudocode. I just need to see it actually work before I can move forward and python is the only language I "know", sort of.

Comment: understandable :) Check my answer below as to how you can make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to use a "global" variable in your class, assign the variables to `self.variable_name` as such:

```
class Date:
    month = int
    day = int
    year = int
    def setDate(self, month, day, year):
        HIGH_MONTH = 12
        HIGHEST_DAYS = [None,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        if month > HIGH_MONTH:
            month = HIGH_MONTH
        elif month < 1:
            month = 1
        else:
            month = month
        if day > HIGHEST_DAYS[month]:
            day = HIGHEST_DAYS[month]
        elif day < 1:
            day = 1
        else:
            day = day
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
    def showDate(self):
        print 'Date:',self.month,'/',self.day,'/',self.year
```

---

```
>>> birthday=Date()
>>> graduation=Date()
>>> birthday.month=6
>>> birthday.day=24
>>> birthday.year=1984
>>> graduation.setDate(5,36,2016)
>>> birthday.showDate()
Date: 6 / 24 / 1984
>>> graduation.showDate()
Date: 5 / 31 / 2016
>>>
```

Comment: Oh wow. That actually solves several issues I was having but didn't know how to ask. Thank you @A.J.

Comment: @KirkStevenson no problem, if my answer helped you, would you mind +1ing it? Thanks!

Comment: you are the first person I am allowed to +1. Done!